# Getting z- index issue when i see video in 768 resolution in safari and IE8

Tags: html, ipad, css, safari

Right now i am getting a video z-index issue in Ie8 and safari browsers.

[enter link description here](http://www.creativecorp.in/tcg/index.html)

When i take look in 760 resolution this page video showing is top even i used z-index reduce also it is not taking any properties.
Please scroll up and down if you want see the issue but take look at 760 resolution and let me know any solution.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yup I am aware of this youtube video bug, just add `?wmode=transparent` in your url and it will fix this : [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/S9PuP/1/)

So now your url will look like this

`http://www.youtube.com/embed/qcYx4SCYRVU?wmode=transparent`